Can I Use TensorFlow RNN Layers (LSTMs, GRUs, etc.) with the Universal Sentence Encoder?
Is there a way to attach the USE as an embedding layer to a Recursive Neural Network (RNN) or a Bi-directional RNN? I got a value error trying to add it to a Sequential model. I am open to using the functional model construction syntax, e.g.
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding='same', data_format='channels_last')(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(x)

I want to avoid using Lambda layers. I want to ensure I can save my model in the .h5 format, not just a TensorFlow-specific format.
This is a snippet of the code I tried.
sentence_encoder_layer = tf_hub.KerasLayer(
    "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4",
    input_shape=[],
    dtype=tf.string,
    trainable=False,
    name="USE"
)

def define_rnn_with_universal_encoder():
    sigmoid_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
        units = 5,
        activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax,
        use_bias=True,
        kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
        bias_initializer='zeros',
        name='1_vs_5_sigmoid'
    )

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        sentence_encoder_layer,
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
            layer=tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)
        ),
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
            layer=tf.keras.layers.GRU(128, return_sequences=False)
        ),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name='flatten'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            units=128,
            activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
            name='Dense_1_128'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            units=64,
            activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
            name='Dense_2_64'),
        sigmoid_layer,
    ], name='model')

    optimizer_adam=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
        learning_rate=0.001,
        beta_1=0.9,
        beta_2=0.999,
        epsilon=1e-07,
        amsgrad=False,
        name='Adam'
    )

    model.compile(
        loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
        optimizer = optimizer_adam,
        # optimizer = optimizer_sgd,
        metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]
        # metrics = ['categorical_accuracy']
    )

    print('Summary:\n', model.summary())
    return model

This is the error I got:
ValueError: Only instances of keras.Layer can be added to a Sequential model. Received: <tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer object at 0x7f62bb2c0310> (of type <class 'tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer'>)
